# CPT Archive Pagination - Page not found

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, rewrite-rules

I have the following code to register my CPT, related taxonomy and rewrite rules.

```
$store_name = 'store'
add_action('init', function () use ($store_name) {
  register_post_type(
    'my_sample_cpt',
    array(
      'public'      => true,
      'has_archive'  => $store_name,
    )
  );
  register_taxonomy(
    'collection',
    'my_sample_cpt',
    array(
      'label' => __('Collection'),
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => $store_name),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'show_admin_column' => true,
    )
  );

  add_rewrite_tag('%collection%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%pageno%', '(\d+)');

  add_rewrite_rule($store_name . '/([^/]*)/page/(\d+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=my_sample_cpt&collection=$matches[1]&pageno=$matches[2]', 'top');
  add_rewrite_rule($store_name . '/page/(\d+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=my_sample_cpt&pageno=$matches[1]', 'top');

  flush_rewrite_rules(false);
}, 100);
```

The following URLs are working fine

- example.com/store/
- example.com/store/my-collection/
- example.com/store/my-collection/page/2/

**but when I hit the below URL, it says page not found**

- example.com/store/page/2/

**This is the corresponding rewrite rule I used for achieving the URL structure.**

```
add_rewrite_rule($store_name . '/page/(\d+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=my_sample_cpt&pageno=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

any advice, some code?

Comment: Hook `parse_request` and have a look at the `matched_rule` property of the request object to see which rule was matched on your problem requests. Installing something like rewrite rule inspector might also be helpful.

Comment: @t31os Here is what I got from Rewrite Rules Inspector [ https://imgur.com/a/UsK0bd9 ], I can see my custom rule up top.

Comment: If you leave the URL part blank and simply use the rule source dropdown, you can filter down to all rules for your type. That's beside the point anyway, what you really need to know right now is which rule is being applied during your problem request(s), which was the first part of my previous comment (hooking on `parse_request`).